# tracking showing straight lines instead points in array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova

I am making a real time Tracker which is sending latitude and longitude to server and then i am drawing a poly line 
on the basis of points but the problem is its not drawing according poly line .its showing straight lines. i using google map api v3 javascript and simply showing a simple polyline.i do not know why it it not drawing according points 
.can anybody please help me to make it smooth.

i am saving points every 30 seconds but still it draws big straight lines.it should draw small lines connecting with each point?
this is my coding

```
function initialize(data, total) {

 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var mapOptions = {
    zoom : 15,
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(28.5475468, 77.2112022),

};
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

 var mypath = new Array();

 //  Parse the array of LatLngs into Gmap points
 for(var i=0; i <= total; i++){
     //Tokenise the coordinates
 //    alert(i);
      mypath.push(new google.maps.LatLng( data[i].lat_position, data[i].long_position ));
 }

 var lineSymbol = {
            path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            scale: 4
          };


          // Create the polyline, passing the symbol in the 'icons' property.
          // Give the line an opacity of 0.
          // Repeat the symbol at intervals of 20 pixels to create the dashed effect.
          var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: mypath,
            strokeOpacity: 0,
            icons: [{
              icon: lineSymbol,
              offset: '0',
            }],
            map: map
          });
        }

///////////////////////////data which is coming from server///////////////////////////////
 public function getmeaddressAction(){
       $boyid=$_POST['id'];
       //echo $boyid; die;
        $output=$this->_model->getmeaddress($boyid);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($output);     
         die;
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////// and model is////////////////////////////

function getmeaddress($boyid)
{
$sql='select * from trackposition where delivery_boy_id='.$boyid.'  order by id ASC ';
$data=$this->fetchAll($sql);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: How do you push `data` into `initialize()` which is started on load and did you check your `data` inside `initialize()` function?

Comment: @AntoJurković ok i think i did a mistake here.i change it .thanks

Comment: @AntoJurković http://test.hbrank.com/track/tracking?dbyid=2.its a link of my application.you can see its still drawing lines straight

Comment: @AntoJurković i am in trouble ,can you please help me??

Comment: From link you provided I receive bunch of errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: getAllData is not defined ` and others. Could you provides some lines of `data`?

Comment: Not that. Content of data variable in initialize() function

Comment: 28.5273472,77.2153879
28.5308728,77.218783
28.5273472,77.2153879
in latitude,longitude form.

Comment: if you get lat,lng per line of data then you can do: var latLng = data[i].split(','); and then use latLng[0] and latLng[1] in LatLng method. Cannot explain better now

Comment: thanks so much for your valuable reply.i just changed the things and applied your method but the thing data length is 37 but if we show markers then it shows only 3 points.

Comment: Inspect values which are coming out of `data`. Try with `parseFloat(latLng[0])` and `parseFloat(latLng[1])`.

Comment: @AntoJurković thanks for your support.i find the problem.the problem was -:my location`s latitude and longitude are not accurate and they are not updating according to location.even i am using set timeout method to call location again and again but it is still showing past coordinates.